# Copying several records from a Query

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a data model, Material, that has related chemicalProperty model. Each material may have several chemical properties.
I want the users to be able to create a new Material record based on an existing one and to create at the same time a copy of its related chemicalProperty records to go along.

I know how to create several records from an array and I know how to make a query.
Is there a way to create an array from a query?
or is there another way to copy several records changing the forgein key in the process?

Here is the code I have right now.

Any help is appreciated.

```html
function duplicateChemicalProperties(oldMaterialId, newMaterialId) {
   
/* var query = app.models.Propiedad_Quimica.newQuery();
*  query.filters.Material_fk._equals = oldMaterialId;
*  var recordData = query.run()[0];*/
  
  var recordData = [
   ["1",new Date,userId,new Date,userId,"H2O",,"2",,".5","algun tipo de tolerancia","comentarios"],
   ["2",new Date,userId,new Date,userId,"Algodon de azucar ",,"6",,"10","tolerancia","Notas"]
   ];

  var records = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < recordData.length; i++) {    
    var record = app.models.Propiedad_Quimica.newRecord();
    record.Material_fk =  newMaterialId; 
    record.Fecha_Creacion = recordData[i][1];
    record.Usuario_Creacion = recordData[i][2];
    record.Fecha_Edicion = recordData[i][3];
    record.Usuario_Edicion = recordData[i][4];
    record.Analisis =  recordData[i][5];
    record.P_Min = recordData[i][6];
    record.P_Max = recordData[i][7];
    record.P_Tipico = recordData[i][8];
    record.Tolerancia = recordData[i][9];
    record.Tipo_de_tolerancia = recordData[i][10];
    record.Comentarios = recordData[i][11];


    records.push(record);
  }
  app.saveRecords(records);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```javascript
function duplicateChemicalProperties(oldMaterialId, newMaterialId) {
  var query = app.models.Propiedad_Quimica.newQuery();
  query.filters.Material_fk._equals = oldMaterialId;
  var existingRecords = query.run();

  var newRecords = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < existingRecords.length; i++) {
    var existingRecord = existingRecords[i];
    var newRecord = app.models.Propiedad_Quimica.newRecord();

    newRecord.Material_fk =  newMaterialId;
    newRecord.Fecha_Creacion = existingRecord.Fecha_Creacion;
    newRecord.Usuario_Creacion = existingRecord.Usuario_Creacion;
    ...

    newRecords.push(newRecord);
  }

  app.saveRecords(newRecords);
}
```

Depending on the data flow the algorithm could be optimized with [prefetches](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/api/server#Query) and [Models Metadata API](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/api/server#ModelMetadata)